# update_attributes is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's my controller

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController 
  def exercises
    if current_user.userprofile.present? #chef whether there is a userprofile object
     @weeknum = current_user.userprofile.week 
     @dayly_activity = Activity.where(:week => 1, :day => 'Monday').first   
    end #end check userprofile     
  end

 def updatexercises
   respond_to do | format | 
    @dayly_activity = Activity.where(:week => 1, :day => 'Monday').first 
    @dayly_activity.update_attributes(params[:@dayly_activity])  
    @dayly_activity.save 
    format.html { render action: "exercises" }
  end
 end  
end
```

And my template

```
<h1>WEEKLY EXERCICES</h1>

Day : <%= @dayly_activity.day %>

<%= form_for(@dayly_activity, :url => { :action => "updatexercises" }) do | f | %>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Jogging:</td>
    <td>
        <% list = (0..20).to_a %>
        <%= f.select :jog, list %>
        x 0.1 km
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bicycling:</td>
    <td>
        <% list = (0..10).to_a %>
        <%= f.select :bicycl, list %>
        km
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Push ups:</td>
    <td>
        <% list = (0..20).to_a %>
        <%= f.select :pushups, list %>
        x 10 times
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan = "2"><%= f.submit %></td>
</tr>
  </table>

<% end %>
```

When I click the button, the Daily+activity object is not being saved. Am I missing some thing

## EDIT

I've tried to hard code this way and it saving to the database.

```
@dayly_activity.jog = 17
@dayly_activity.pushups = 13
@dayly_activity.save
```

Obviously, the problem must be with the **update_attributes**

Comment: `params[:@dayly_activity]` remove `@`

Comment: Is that the only problem? I've removed the @ sign, It still not saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `params[:dayly_activity]` (drop the @ sign).

Also, I would put these two lines :

```
   @dayly_activity = Activity.where(:week => 1, :day => 'Monday').first 
   @dayly_activity.update_attributes(params[:dayly_activity])
```

Outside of your `respond_to` block (put them on top of it).

You can also drop the `@dayly_activity.save`, update_attributes do it automatically and will returns true/false  if it works/fails.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in `[:@dayly_activity]`

And in that code

```
@dayly_activity.update_attributes(params[:@dayly_activity])  
@dayly_activity.save
```

`save` is useless. `update_attributes` saving the record.

It better to check result of `update_attributes`. So you can catch validation errors.

For example

```
if @dayly_activity.update_attributes(params[:dayly_activity]) 
  redirect_to dayli_activity_path, :notice => "Updated"
else
  render :edit
end
```