# update_attributes is not saving values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I went to through various similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093922/update-attributes-isnt-saving-to-the-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535945/update-attributes-is-not-working), but that did not solve it for me.

My controller code.

```
# GET `/reservations/new`
  def new
    @user_id = current_user.id
    if current_user.has_reserved
        format.html { redirect_to reservations_url, notice: 'Only one reservation per customer is allowed' }
     end
    @car_id = params[:car_id]
    @c = Car.where(:id => @car_id).first
    puts "Hello"
    puts @c.id
    puts @c.update_attributes({:status => 'reserved'})
    puts @c.status
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end
```

This is my console, when I visit the page.

```
Hello
4
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
true
reserved
```

Now when I check the database in rails console

```
Car.where(:status => 'reserved')
```

This gives me no values. (Even `Car.all` shows all car's status as 'available' which is the default)

Output of above :

```
irb(main):009:0> Car.where(:status => 'reserved')
  Car Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."status" = ? LIMIT ?  [["status", "reserved"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

As I gathered from other questions, `update_attributes` saves the record also. And it's returning true. Then why is it not reflecting in database?

Edit : Adding Model File Code

Car.rb

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
    validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => ['available','reserved','checked_out'], :default => 'available'
    validates_inclusion_of :style, :in => ['coupe','sedan','suv'], :default => 'sedan'
    validates_length_of :licence_plate, :is => 7, :unique => true
    attr_accessor :status
end
```

Reservation.rb

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car
  attr_accessor :can_checkout, :can_return, :can_reserve, :checked_out, :returned
end
```

Code from where `reservation/new` is called,'views/cars/index.html.erb'.

```
<td><%= link_to "Reserve", controller: "reservations", action: "new", car_id: car.id%></td>
```

Comment: Why you update the record Inside the 'new' action of the controller ? Usually the new action loads a record if needed, then the new view contains a form to create a new recod, and then the form is submitted to the update action to save the record to the database ... Can you copy the code of the new view of the réservations controller ?

Comment: don't use puts. Use logger.debug or whatever level you want to log at. puts is not for rails output

Comment: regarding my comment above, I mean 'create action' not 'update action'

Comment: this `new` is for reserations. Where I am trying to update the attributes of `car`. @Maxence

Comment: Will do that, thanks @jamesc

Comment: Can you please paste all your model files code pls. But there are a few things I struggle to understand. For example, where do you get `params[:car_id]` value from ? params is a value that is passed by a form, but you are in the new action of your controller ... (i say that because it is usually in the 'new' view that the form is located, how can it be available in the new action of the controller ...?)

Comment: I agree that the reservation should occur in the create action and not in the new action. What happens to the car if the user changes their mind before completing a reservation? The car status would remain in the 'reserved' status.

Comment: @Maxence, I have updated the question.

Comment: You should run this code in the rails console. And try @c.update_attributes!({:status => 'reserved'}) to see if you are failing a validation or some other error is occuring.

Comment: There are too many things that could happen between running the new action and running the console. are you even running in the same environment. Put a find in to get a new instance of the record as the last thing that you do in the new method and log the status of the new instance. to prove that it is not working. So far you have proved nothing. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @AytanLeibowitz, it still does not solve the problem if I put that in `create`. Is there some alternative?

Comment: Try this in the console:

`car = Car.find(4)`
`car.update_attributes!({:status => 'reserved'})`

Any errors in the console?

Comment: Ok so if I understand well, the user can see all the cars available (index view of cars) then click on the link to create a reservation. Then (ok i understand now) you direct him to the new action of reservation in order to create a reservation for this car. you also pass an extra param: car_id (i didnt understand why you had this param in your new action). So now what you want to set the 'car.status'  to reserved and then probably ask more information to your user... I guess there will be a form in the reservation new view.. regarding status, why don't you do `@c.status='reserved'` `@c.save `

Comment: You may be changing the car's status, but if any of the other validations fail then it will not save to the database. The reason `@c.status` outputs `reserved` is because you changed the value for the object, but it has not persisted to the database because of a validation failure.

Comment: another thing: reservation belongs to both user and car, but car doesn't own reservation. you should have something like this in the car model file car.rb: `has_many :reservations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit form action of reservation's 'new' view would call the 'create' method of the reservation controller to which you can pass your car_id as a parameter. Then in the submit method you can get the associated car by **@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])** and try updating the car status

Answer (score 2):

Does the car have a **status** field in the database?

If so, why do you use **attr_accessor :status**? in the model. It is not necessary if the field exists.

Remove the **attr_accessor** and add the field in the database if it is not present.